# How do I implement __str__ that will print values in my lists in a formatted form?

Tags: python, list, class

I have a self-defined class that stores a list of keys and values and I want to implement `__str__` so that when I print the class object, it will produce a formatted output.

I have my class like this:

```
class List:
   def __init__(self, key, value):
       self.key = key
       self.value = value
   def __str__(self):
       #code
```

I'm not sure how to implement `__str__` that the output will look like this when I print an object instance:

```
list1 = List(['a','b','c'],[1,2,3])
print(list1)
```

Output:

```
a    1
b    2
c    3
```

My approach was this:

```
def __str__(self):
    for i in range(len(self.value)):
        yield(f"{self.value[i]:>10} {self.index[i]:>5}")
```

However, I'm getting type generator error. I'm assuming using yield is not appropriate in this case. How do I print?

Comment: `__str__` should return a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class List:
   def __init__(self, keys, values):
       self.keys = keys
       self.values = values

   def __str__(self):
       return '\n'.join([f"{key}\t{value}" for key, value in zip(self.keys, self.values)])
```

Comment: This might be a good place to use `zip` rather than indexing using values from a `range`.

Comment: Thanks, @Blckknght replaced index with zip